# Oracle : compare field date with actual date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I use this request for obtein line who has the field date is equal of actual date as this :

```
SELECT * FROM TB_VUE_SOLDE WHERE SO_COMPTE_ID = 661 AND SO_DATE = SYSDATE;
```

with this request my result is empty

in table TB_VUE_SOLDE :

```
(63162, 661, 22/01/14, 41188)
```

The field SO_DATE have DATE Type

when i try to display the sysdate like this :

```
SELECT SYSDATE "Actual date" FROM DUAL ;
```

I obtein : 22/01/14

why i can't obtein the result in my first request ?

Comment: What is the datatype of SO_DATE and SO_COMPTE_ID in database ?

Comment: SO_DATE (DATE), So_COMPTE_ID (INT)

Comment: Do you get anything when you remove `AND SO_DATE....`

Comment: YES, i got the line (63162, 661, 22/01/14, 41188)

Comment: `SELECT * FROM TB_VUE_SOLDE WHERE SO_COMPTE_ID = 661 AND SO_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE)`

Comment: Try using CURRENT_DATE

Comment: Thank's @MaheswaranRavisankar, it work's with TRUNC

Comment: @tchiko `SYSDATE` returns date with `TIMESTAMP` details too, and that is the issue for you, when compared against a `DATE` column without timestamp info. `TRUNC()` of removes the timestamp information.

Comment: DATE is not a date - http://jeffkemponoracle.com/2012/06/22/date-is-not-a-date/

Answer (score 2):

SYSDATE will include a time element.

Try

```
  SELECT * FROM TB_VUE_SOLDE WHERE SO_COMPTE_ID = 661 AND SO_DATE = TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

Trunc will remove the time element.

Answer (score 0):

If you do an

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
```

and then execute

```
SELECT SYSDATE "Actual date" FROM DUAL ;
```

you will see that `sysdate` is not only the day but also contains hours, minutes and seconds.

This is why is highly probable that sysdate is `!=` the date that you selected on.

Answer (score 0):

I've add TRUNC before date and it works